# How to find if FC-Switch using port-zoning or not Brocade FC 300

Tags: san

I have to replace a HBA on RedHat5.3 due to card failure.

A tech guy asked me that "Check your FC-Switch Zoning Type of Port Zoning or not? , because if host accessed by WWNN, you'll need to update FC-switch config"

Is this below result on Brocade FC 300 showing Port-Zoning configuration or not?

```
fcsw03:admin> switchshow
switchName:     xxxxx
switchType:     71.2
switchState:    Online
switchMode:     Native
switchRole:     Principal
switchDomain:   1
switchId:       fffc01
switchWwn:      10:00xxxxxxxxxxxxx
zoning:         ON (zones)
switchBeacon:   OFF

Index Port Address Media Speed State     Proto
==============================================
  0   0   011700   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  1   1   011500   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 21:00:00:24:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  2   2   011300   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  3   3   011100   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  4   4   011600   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  5   5   011400   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  6   6   011200   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:60:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  7   7   011000   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:69:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  8   8   010f00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
  9   9   010d00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 10  10   010b00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 11  11   010900   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 12  12   010e00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 13  13   010c00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 14  14   010a00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 15  15   010800   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is to check *zoneshow* command output to list all configured zones. Zones that look like:

```
zone:test_1
         21:00:00:24:XX:XX:XX:XX
         50:06:01:60:XX:XX:XX:XX
         50:06:01:69:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Are using WWN addresses.

If you see something like:

```
zone:test_1
         1,1
         1,6
         1,7
```

Then, you are using port-zoning. Here, the first 1 is the SwitchDomain ID and 1,6,7 are port numbers on that switch.

Also, zones can have a mixture of WWNs and ports definitions. Don't forget to do the same on the second Brocade switch as they are usually implementing Dual-Fabric configuration for redundancy and multi-pathing.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since port based zoning and wwn based zoning had anything to do with hand vs soft zone enforcement. At least since FOS 6.x, hardware enforced zoning applies to both port defined zones and wwn defined zones.